# SSAS Dynamic Set with wrong values when filtered by Year

Tags: ssas, mdx

The idea is to have the top Collaborators by Cost. The problem is, when i wanna see per year, only work if i select the year and use it on dimension. If i drag to see more than one year, the value is not the correct (because the calculation is the same, but for 2 years, instead of the 2 years separated). The set:

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET [Top]
AS  TOPCOUNT
([Collaborator].[Nr Collaborator].[Nr Collaborator].MEMBERS
, ([Measures].[Nr Collaborator Distinct]*0.05)
, [Measures].[Cost]);
```

Comment: Add [Date].[Year].CURRENTMEMBER to your Dynamic Set

Comment: @mxix, like this? Not working. The result is equal now in all years.
TOPCOUNT
(([Collaborator].[Nr Collaborator].[Nr Collaborator].MEMBERS,[Date].[Year].CURRENTMEMBER)
, ([Measures].[Nr Collaborator Distinct]*0.05)
, [Measures].[Cost])

Comment: @mxix Also tried like this, but still not working right. 
CREATE  DYNAMIC SET [Top]
AS GENERATE([Date].[Year].[Year].MEMBERS, TOPCOUNT
([Date].[Year].CURRENTMEMBER*[Collaborator].[Nr Collaborator].[NrCollaborator].MEMBERS
, ([Measures].[Nr Collaborator Distinct]*0.05)
, [Measures].[Cost]));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution, if anyone need it:

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET [Top]
AS GENERATE( {[Date].[Year].[Year].MEMBERS}, TOPCOUNT
(EXISTING [Collaborator].[Nr Collaborator].[Nr Collaborator].MEMBERS
, ([Measures].[Nº Collaborators Distincts]*0.05)
, [Measures].[Cost]));
```